# OpenVPN Android

Tags: android, x509certificate, vpn, keystore, openvpn

I would like to create custom VPN application based on OpenVPN for Android OS. The way I guess this should be done is first compile with NDK the OpenVPN client, then make GUI, which will communicate over JNI with the Open VPN program and then also install custom certificates into cert store. Is something like this possible? Is it difficult? I have seen some open source solutions, so I will probably start with them, but **any tips or suggestions will be great**!

Is it possible that it will include tun-module?

Thanks a lot

BR

STeN

---

*Added later: I have seen some solutions available on the Internet. must be the device rooted in order to use the OpenVPN? I saw there (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2809908/android-vpn-at-the-native-layer) nice description and I can understand the reasons for that since VPN works on IP level and creates the interface for the whole system... Are there some other ways?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Android 4.0 this is possible now. See the VPNService API. For OpenVPN there is already an app that uses this API (https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure it is compatible with MS-VPN (OpenVPN AFAIK does not work with MS based VPN solutions).

Comment: Hi, do you mean compatibility with Microsoft solution?

Comment: Yes. Currently no native android device can connect to a Microsoft VPN. For example, I cannot connect my phone to our Microsoft VPN at work. There are non-native applications that can complete this from what I understand, but the lack of being able to connect to an MS VPN will keep Android from being fully adopted by the corporate market.